# Can't start MySQL on Mac OS X getting mysql.sock connection error

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I'm trying to get MySQL running on my Mac. I used macports for the initial install but can't get past this mysql socket error.
Note: macports appends the version number to commands if they look odd below.

**Error:**

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'

I get this error when:

> mysqladmin5 -u root password
>   and also
>   mysql5 -u root -p

**My install and start process**
Installed mysql with macports:

> sudo port install mysql5 +server
>   sudo /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql

Started like this:

> sudo /opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5

Also tried:

> sudo /opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server start

**How I've tried to solve this**
I tried adding to the my.cnf file

> [mysqld_safe] socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

Only problem is there wasn't a my.cnf file to begin with so I'm not sure if I created it in the right place.

I was also going to sim link the mysql.sock file to the /tmp dir but there's no mysql.sock file anywhere on the system.

So I created a mysql.sock file

> touch /tmp/mysql.sock
>   But this didn't work either.

I'm thinking maybe I missed something in the install process since I can't find the my.cnf or mysql.sock file on the system.

Here's the guide I used:
http://2tbsp.com/content/install_and_configure_mysql_5_macports

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it isn't already running?

Comment: Could you post what is in the config file? The file is `my.cnf` and it is found in `/etc/`.

Comment: I confirmed this on my Macbook Air. I installed mysql55 with macports and I can start the server locally and log in. If I try to tunnel to a server, I cannot log in. I get the same error. I am sure the port is correctly forwarded because I can log in using Sequel Pro just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Find your mysql.sock then create a symlink from /tmp/mysql.sock to that path

```
locate mysql.sock
ln -s /path/to/real/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest getting the MySQL OSX package from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html#macosx-dmg

These work just fine and include the startup scripts and a MySQL preferences pane.

Answer (score 0):

The following was posted by Jonathan Bexiga on the MySQL forums & it worked for me.  Basically don't use sudo when starting up.

I had also created the symlink as previously referenced, so that may also be required as part of the fix.

> I found the fix. For anyone else who
>   may run into this exact problem what
>   you need to do is log in as root. Open
>   up terminal. Type
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_safe. Hit
>   ctrl+z. Then type
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql. It worked
>   for me.

Comment: Dude, that is a normal MySQL install, not from MacPorts. Different issue. Notice all Macports are in /opt/local/